# ZOS: Create first member of dataset

Tags: dataset, mainframe, zos

I'm using ZOS with ISPF 7.1

I have allocated a dataset with the following information:

[image]

I'm trying to create the first member of this dataset through the **Edit Entry Panel** (it's option 2 on the menu):

[image]

But I always end up with a *"Member not found"* message.

I know this panel can edit members that already exist, but what is the correct way to create the first member of a dataset (without copying)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISPF Edit does not like a RECFM of U (undefined). So you can't do what you are asking with the library.

The message isn't correct, but I don't suppose people see it that often. You can report that to IBM (ask your Technical Support to raise a PMR). Then at some point in the future you'll have a warm feeling when you do the same thing and it produces an accurate message.

If you put members into that dataset with a "copy" and then try to get a member-selection list for Edit, you'll see a message that "Browse was substituted". This is the source of your first message. Recfm U causes the switch to Browse, you can't have a "new" member in Browse, so it looks for an old one, which isn't found.

If you genuinely want RECFM U, you're not going to be able to edit with ISPF.

If instead, from the LRECL and BLOCKSIZE, you wanted RECFM F (fixed-length records) then you'll need to delete and reallocate the dataset with F.

A good way to allocate a new library is to use 3.2 and firstly just list a similar existing library (leave the command area blank is how you do that, and enter the library name in the obvious place).

Then when you A for Allocate, it will "fill in" the parameters of the library you have just listed, and you can make any necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

Option 0 In ISPF Primary Option Menu is for PDF Environment settings.for example:
   __  Allow empty member list
   __  Allow empty member list (nomatch)
   __  Empty member list for edit only 
change them and test.

Answer (score 0):

Got me 5 years to answer this one :D
Actually it's a very normal behavior. You created a PDS but there are any members inside. Simplest is to go to ISPF edit and in the dataset name type name of your dataset and in brackets the new member name - hlq.data.set.name(member01).